# What does PC1 mean in prcomp output?

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm having trouble trying to understand the output of the `prcomp` function from package `stats` in `R`.

Below is the output of the function.
My concern is if  PC1 means column 1 and so on.

This is since I am trying to understand the variance of the columns through the columns so my clustering algorithm can use less columns.

```
             PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4         PC5         PC6
column1      -0.1182514  0.46119191 -0.59081719 -0.06185461  0.355082373  0.15779136
column2       0.1327832 -0.38247607 -0.56927572  0.36595097  0.382311915 -0.21166970
column3       0.3911240  0.31724820 -0.30998334 -0.17641298 -0.464012126 -0.49115595
column4       0.3283022 -0.31804337  0.14057974 -0.61262993  0.502428689 -0.02037630
column5       0.4385145  0.25196223  0.03869783  0.25461395  0.018291891  0.70032718
column6       0.6248343  0.08194069 -0.01284221 -0.16182097 -0.009914833  0.01535703
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PC1` means the first principal component, the direction that carries the most variance.

You can project your data onto the first few components and perform clustering. You might like to look at `sdev` output to read off the standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you Siong for the response. Do you have any resource that explain how to project the data based on the pca result?

Comment: [This](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/practical-guide-principal-component-analysis-python/) might help.

Comment: Thank you. I'm marking your answer as correct.